# Archiving folders while maintaining folder structure

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing

I have a Windows SBS 2008 server that is mostly used for file storage & exchange.

Currently everything is under one folder, that is mapped to each computer.

I want to move all documents that are over 2 or 3 years old into another folder (that would be mapped as another drive), while maintaining folder structure in both the source and destination.

The old data may still need to be used. Any ideas team?

Thanks,
Sam

**UPDATE**

I have been using this command:

```
robocopy /COPYALL /MINAGE:365 /V /MOVE "C:\Source" "C:\Dest"
```

for testing, which has been copying the files, but not deleting them from the source location, even though I use */MOVE*

Am I doing something wrong here or is there another way to do this? :)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What's the actual goal?

Comment: Currently the drives are being synchronized to laptops using Sync Center and it is far too much data.

Comment: Do you have delete rights? Can you manually, via CMD's built-in MOVE or the Explorer GUI, move a file between these destinations? Does robocopy's exit message explain why files weren't deleted from the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool like robocopy (reskit or now mart of Win2k8 server) to copy files that have changed before a certain date.  XCopy will do the same thing but robocopy has a richer set of features.

Of course you will want to copy a significant portion of the data to a test area so you can fine tune your process.

As @mfinni suggests, more details about your desired outcome would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to refine this into the command: `robocopy /e /copyall /minage:0 /v /mov "C:\Testing\Source" "c:\testing\destination"` which works now. I guess I was having a permission issue with deleting the source before :)

Answer (score 1):

I think Robocopy should do the trick for you.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx